# Jquery Page out transition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using Jquery page out transition animation effect and targeting any `<a>` on the page.

The question here , can I target also all `<button>` and `<input type="button">` ?

The code:

```
 pageOut: function($self) {
  var _this = this;
  var $this = $(this);
  var url = $self.attr("href");
  var outClass = methods.pageOutClass.call(_this, $self);
  var outDuration = methods.pageOutDuration.call(_this, $self);
  $this.css({
    "animation-duration": outDuration / 1e3 + "s"
  }).addClass(outClass);
  setTimeout(function() {
    location.href = url;
  }, outDuration);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can target all `<a>`, `<button>`, and `<input type="button">` with:

```
$('a, button, input[type="button"]')
```

Comment: ok but it's targeting `<a>` from the attribute `herf`
`var url = $self.attr("href");`

Comment: and here is the js file 
https://github.com/blivesta/animsition/blob/master/src/js/animsition.js

Comment: I'm using the same file from github above

Comment: When I click any `<a>` link it makes fade out transition 

I think that's the main idea

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183920/discussion-between-chris-happy-and-gamal-elwazeery).

Comment: I made it by adding "animsition-link" class with jquery addclass :)

Comment: @GamalElwazeery Great to hear! Well done :) God bless.